# Sum array values with sum equals X

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, sum

I have an integer collection. I need to get all possibilites that sum of values are equal to X.

I need something like [this](http://gofrom.us/FQ4).

It can be written in: delphi, c#, php, RoR, python, cobol, vb, vb.net

Comment: No, we need to find all possibilites of tax values that we dont sent to governament.

Comment: And my dificult is because I have about 60 dates diferences and avg 500 values/day. SO, I need the fast method.

Comment: Due to its lack of orthography I have problems parsing the grammar of your first comment, Zote.  And by the way, since you already have found the answer in a different question, why don't you implement that?  Finally, stackoverflow is _not_ getacoder.com.

Comment: Based on your explanation, I suppose X is fairly small?  In that case the dynamic programming approach suggested by Ben S should be fast.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's a [subset sum problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem). And it is [NP-Complete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-complete).

The only way to implement this would be generate all possible combinations and compare the sum values. Optimization techniques exists though.

Here's one in C#:

```
static class Program
{
    static int TargetSum = 10;
    static int[] InputData = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };

    static void Main()
    {
        // find all permutations
        var permutations = Permute(InputData);

        // check each permutation for the sum
        foreach (var item in permutations) {

            if (item.Sum() == TargetSum) {

                Console.Write(string.Join(" + ", item.Select(n => n.ToString()).ToArray()));
                Console.Write(" = " + TargetSum.ToString());
                Console.WriteLine();

            }
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static IEnumerable<int[]> Permute(int[] data) { return Permute(data, 0); }

    static IEnumerable<int[]> Permute(int[] data, int level)
    {
        // reached the edge yet? backtrack one step if so.
        if (level >= data.Length) yield break;

        // yield the first #level elements
        yield return data.Take(level + 1).ToArray();

        // permute the remaining elements
        for (int i = level + 1; i < data.Length; i++) {
            var temp = data[level];
            data[level] = data[i];
            data[i] = temp;

            foreach (var item in Permute(data, level + 1))
                yield return item;

            temp = data[i];
            data[i] = data[level];
            data[level] = temp;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[Dynamic Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming) would yield the best runtime for an exact solution. [The Subset Sum Problem page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem#Pseudo-polynomial_time_dynamic_programming_solution) on Wikipedia has some pseudo-code for the algorithm. Essentially you order all the numbers and add up all the possible sequences in order such that you minimize the number of additions. The runtime is pseudo-polynomial.

For a polynomial algorithm you could use an [Approximation Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximation_algorithm). Pseudo-code is also available at the [Subset Sum Problem page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem#Polynomial_time_approximate_algorithm).

Of the two algorithms I would choose the dynamic programming one since it is straight-forward and has a good runtime with most data sets.

However if the integers are all non-negative and fit with the description on the Wikipedia page then you could actually do this in polynomial time with the approximation algorithm.