# Finding possible combination from an array elements where Sum is equal to

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, combinations

I have a requirement where i have to find a list of combinations where the sum =180.
I have an array of intergers and have to pick up the elements from this array only.

For example :
Array = {30,45,60,15,60,30}
now i as an output should get - 60,60,30,30 or 45,15,60,30,30 or 45,15,60,60

I am trying various approaches but its failing in one or the other scenario. Please suggest implementation in C#.

Please provide inputs.

Thanks

Comment: Please provide what you've tried ... (it's a rather trivial question, but I don't feel the need to solve other people homework if they didn't tried anything ... )

Comment: Possibilities are there, You show your try..This is similar to probability..

Comment: ahhh ... the possibilities ... recursion ... loops ... iterations ... brute force ... smart objects ... energy wielding dogs ... if only the OP have tried something ...

Comment: Sort out array by weight in descending order and use recursively calls to approach to decision. Each call is try to take the next number (stone))) to summarize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Sub set problems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem) solutions can be found everywhere on the net or stack overflow:

Try this:

[Sum array values with sum equals X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/595707/sum-array-values-with-sum-equals-x)