# Find all combinations of a given set of integers summing up to a given sum

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, subset-sum, coin-change

I am looking for an answer to the following problem.

Given a set of integers (no duplicates) and a sum, find all possible combinations of the set's elements summing up to the sum. Solutions order does not matter (solutions {2, 2, 3} and {3, 2 ,2} are equal).

Please note that the final combination does not need to be a set, as it can contain duplicates.

Example:
Set {2,3,5}
Sum 10

Result:
{2, 2, 2, 2, 2}, {2, 2, 3, 3}, {2, 3, 5}, {5, 5}

I've looked at Subset Sum problem as well as Coin Change problem, but couldn't adapt them to suit my needs. I am not really familiar with dynamic programming, so it's probably doable, however I couldn't figure it out.

As I am dealing with a fairly large set of elements (around 50), precomputing all the sets is not an option as it would take a very long time. A way to pull out different solutions from a Subset Sum table would be preferable (if possible).

Any advice, tips, or sample code would be appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sum array values with sum equals X](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/595707/sum-array-values-with-sum-equals-x)

Comment: @TiMr I am sorry, but the that answer is not what I am looking for. There each result is a set (without duplicates), however I am looking for a way to find all solutions including those with multiple occurances of the same element, just like in the example I provided.

Comment: Not really different from subset-sum (it allows sets or multisets) or unbounded knapsack.

Comment: This is *exactly* the coin change problem.  What do you mean you couldn't adapt it to suit your needs?

Comment: You can view this as a special.case of unbounded knapsack, or a generalisation of subset sum. Either way enumerating *all* solitions requires full exhaustive search. One solution may be found with DP.

Comment: @n.m. Having a multiset as an input is not exactly what I am looking for, that's why from my perspective it's not good. Of course I could achieve the same results using this approach, but assuming that I have an infinite supply of each element is what I am looking for.

I am not familiar with DP. Is there really no way to find alternative solutions using DP, only one?

Comment: Do you want to output them all or just count them?

Comment: @wim You are right. It is exactly the same. I looked at coin change problem only from DP perspective and couldn't find a way to find alternative solutions using that method. I will look into different ways to solve coin change problem, not using DP, if any exits.

Comment: @n.m. Output them all.

Comment: "Not familiar with DP" a good time to learn is now. I cannot explain it in a SO comment or even an answer, sorry.

Comment: In that case you are up to a large-ish task. Do you know how many lines you will have to print if your set has all numbers from 1 to 100 and the sum is also 100?

Comment: @n.m. Ok thanks for your time anyway :)
Yes I know. That's why I cannot bruteforce all the solutions, cause it's just too big of a task.

Comment: @wim The coin change problem is normally set up to find the best way to give change (least number of coins), not every possible way.

Comment: Do you expect to be able to print all solutions without visiting each at least once?

Comment: No. The thing is I don't need all the solutions instantly. What I actually hoped to achieve is something like bottom-up approach gives me. Compute the 2d array, store it and later use that to find different solutions.

Answer (score 6):

This is known as the [Change-making problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change-making_problem) and it’s a classic example of [dynamic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming).

Some earlier answers have calculated the total *count* of solutions, whilst the question has asked for an *enumeration* of the possible solutions.

You haven't tagged your question with a language, so here's an implementation in Python.  Adapt it to whatever language you please by using your language's "bag" datatype (the `Counter` is Python's "bag").

```
from collections import Counter

def ways(total, coins):
    ways = [[Counter()]] + [[] for _ in range(total)]
    for coin in coins:
        for i in range(coin, total + 1):
            ways[i] += [way + Counter({coin: 1}) for way in ways[i-coin]]
    return ways[total]
```

The output datatype is a list of bags.

```
>>> for way in ways(total=10, coins=(2,3,5)):
...     coins = (coin for coin,count in way.items() for _ in range(count))
...     print(*coins)
... 
2 2 2 2 2
2 2 3 3
2 3 5
5 5
```

Comment: How do you deal with with duplicates? For example, you can imagine you get to `2 2 3 3` as well as `2 3 3 2`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Haskell function that calculates the answer:

```
partitions 0 xs = [[]]
partitions _ [] = []
partitions n (xxs@(x:xs)) | n < 0 = []
                          | otherwise = (map (x:) (partitions (n-x) xxs)) ++ partitions n xs
```

Examples:

```
*Main>  partitions 1 [1]
[[1]]
*Main>  partitions 5 [1..5]
[[1,1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,2],[1,1,3],[1,2,2],[1,4],[2,3],[5]]
*Main> length $ partitions 10 [1..10]
42
*Main> length $ partitions 20 [1..20]
627
*Main> length $ partitions 40 [1..40]
37338
*Main> partitions 10 [1,2,4]
[[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2],[1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2],[1,1,1,1,1,1,4],[1,1,1,1,2,2,2],[1,1,1,1,2,4],[1,1,2,2,2,2],[1,1,2,2,4],[1,1,4,4],[2,2,2,2,2],[2,2,2,4],[2,4,4]]
```

[Semi-live demo](http://ideone.com/sVPG8G)

Answer (score -1):

Solution  complexity:

- time: O(n*M)
- memory: O(M),

where M is value of sum, n is set size

```
int numberOfSums(Set<Integer> values, int sum) {
    // sumCount[i] -> number of ways to get sum == i 
    int sumCount[] = new int[sum+1];
    sumCount[0] = 1;
    for(int v : values) {
        for(int i=0; i<=sum-v; ++i)
            sumCount[i+v] += sumCount[i];
    }
    return sumCount[sum];
}
```