# How to output the actual coin combination in the minimum change problem using recursion

Tags: python, recursion

Given a list of coin denominations and a target value, I'm trying to make a recursive function that will tell me the smallest possible number of coins I'd need to make that value, and to then show which coins I'd need. eg input coins [1,5,10,25] and target of 6, output should be "You need 2 coins: [1,5]"
I've written a function that tells me how many coins I'd need, but I want to see what the coin combination would be too.

```
# USD - $1, $5, $10, etc.
currency = [1, 5, 10, 20, 50, 100]

# the amount to change - eg $6
amount = 6

cache = dict() 

def recursive_change(currency, amount):
  if amount in cache.keys() is not None:
    return cache[amount]

  # base case
  if amount == 0:
    return 0

  result = amount+1 # initially result is just some high number 
  #I figure amount + 1 is fine because we'd never use more coins than the value (assuming we can't have coins worth less than one)

  for coin in currency:
    if coin <= amount:
      result = min(result, recursive_change(currency, amount-coin) + 1)
  cache[amount]=result
  return result
```

Here's another version I just made - I noticed my initial solution didn't handle impossible inputs well (eg make 6 cents using only nickels and dimes), so now it returns -1 for impossible amounts. It's a bit uglier though, would love some input on making it nicer.

```
def recursive_change(currency, amount):
  if amount in cache.keys():
    return cache[amount]

  # base case
  if amount == 0:
    return 0

  # If we can't make the amount with this coin, return -1
  if amount < 0:
    return -1

  result = -1

  for coin in currency:
    if coin <= amount:
      current_result = recursive_change(currency, amount-coin) 
      if current_result >= 0: 
        if result < 0:
          result = current_result 
        else: 
          result = min(current_result, result) 

  if result < 0:
    result = -1
  else:
    result = result + 1
  cache[amount]=result
  print(cache)
  return result
```

Comment: @wim thanks for your quick response. I wasn't able to find a recursive solution with the link you provided, I only see iterative ones.

Comment: related (DP approach) https://stackoverflow.com/a/41812422/674039.  Iterative code is nicer for this problem, any reason you wanted to use recursion here?

Comment: I'm studying, and I feel like I should be able to solve problems using both iteration and recursion. I think I'll feel like I understand recursion much better if I can do this - and the pattern is probably useful for other things, like if I wanted to find a shortest path recursively I could track what that path was and not just know how long it was.

Answer (score 1):

This solution uses recursion to find the ideal solutions where the greedy algorithm fails, uses a cache so it should be about as fast as the DP iterative approach, and outputs the actual coin combination.

```
# currency denominations
currency = [2,3,15,25]

# the amount to make change for - eg $30
amount = 30

# cache contains the best currency combos for each value: eg cache[7]=[5,1,1]
cache = dict()
def recursive_change(currency, amount):
  if amount in cache.keys():
    return []+cache[amount] # Had to do this [] thing so it passes a copy

  # base case
  if amount == 0:
    return []

  # If we can't make the amount with this coin, return -1
  if amount < 0:
    return [-1]

  best_combo = [-1]

  for coin in currency:
    current_result = recursive_change(currency, amount-coin)
    if current_result == [] or current_result[0] >= 0: 
      current_result.append(coin)  # if we picked a coin, we add it to the list
      if best_combo[0] < 0:
        best_combo = current_result 
        # if we found the first coin combo that works for the current problem, set best so we don't compare to -1 below
      else: 
        # if this isn't the first coin combo that works for the current problem, check to see if it's better than any of the other coin combos
        if len(current_result) < len(best_combo):
          best_combo = current_result

  cache[amount]=[]+best_combo # Had to do this [] thing so it passes a copy
  return best_combo
```

Answer (score 0):

You approach is very inefficient, especially for large sums of money. You should have started generating sums from the highest denominations, not from the lowest. Here's the faster and simpler version that returns the denomination and the number of coins/bills:

```
currency = [1, 5, 10, 20, 50, 100]

def recursive_change(currency, amount):
    for c in reversed(currency) :
        if amount >= c :
            return [(amount // c, c),] + recursive_change( currency, amount % c )
    return []

recursive_change( currency, 6 )
>>> [(1, 5), (1, 1)]
```

that means one coin of `5` and one coin of `1`.

A couple more of test results:

```
>>> recursive_change( currency, 77 )
[(1, 50), (1, 20), (1, 5), (2, 1)]
>>> recursive_change( currency, 99 )
[(1, 50), (2, 20), (1, 5), (4, 1)]
```

Comment: When I tried running this, recursive_change(currency,6) I got different results.
```[(1.2, 5)]```

Comment: @BobbyBattista there are no `floats`, please, use `int` everywhere.

Comment: @BobbyBattista ok, probably `//` will do the trick for python3 you're using

Comment: @BobbyBattista please, try the latest version of the code

Comment: Yup, got it. ```return [(int(amount / c), c),] + rc( currency, amount % c )``` worked. What is the comma just before the closing bracket?

Comment: How can I handle impossible ones? For example, many amounts are impossible if I don't have a $1 in my currencies list. Also, can I still use a cache to optimize this?

Comment: @BobbyBattista you cannot optimize this code, it's the best it can be, no need for any cache. if you don't have $1 -- you'll give as much change as you can, and that's it -- could be less than required, but what else can you do if you don't have $1 ?

Comment: when I try asking for 30, given currencies [1,15,25], it should give me [(2, 15)], but instead I get [(1,25), (5,1)]. That's 6 coins instead of 2. Can we fix this?